# Select pivot item

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am looping through each item of a pivot table column and i want to select / activate each of that cells. How can I write this to active the cell of the pivotitem that is being looped?

Comment: What have you tried?? Please produce some [Minimal, Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
Sub TryThis()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")
For Each cell In rng
    cell.Select
Next cell
End Sub
```

For a dynamic range, see the link below.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range

Comment: hi, thank you for the fast answer. The problem is that I do not know the range, I do not know how many elements the Pivot Table has. So, my plan is to go through each item of a particular column of the pivot table. But how do i select/activate each cell while looping? pivotfields.PivotItems.select does not work. thank you!

Comment: i am posting the code in the next comment. the aim is to change the color of a particular word in the pivot table.But in the pivot I don't know how to activate the cell that is looped. Because the code references the activecell.characters

Comment: Set pt = Sheets("Comments").PivotTables("Com")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Comment")
    
    For item = 1 To pf.PivotItems.Count
        x = pf.PivotItems(item).Value
        strSearch = "set"
       firstChar = InStr(x, strSearch)
       Do While firstChar > 0
         ActiveCell.Characters(firstChar, Len(strSearch)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
         firstChar = InStr(firstChar + 1, x, strSearch)
       Loop
   Next item

Comment: I just updated my answer.